personalize your web appearance appears during automation. How To disable it?
While executing the automation code I'm getting personalize your web appearance dialog box appears. It requires manual intervention to click the button 'Got it'. After which I get it as 'Chat closed. connecting again'
How to avoid this?
Here's the image link.
https://github.com/Keerthana-17/Automation/blob/main/Screenshot_20240411_145915.png

Better show your code as text, and put image directly instead of link to external server.

why do you have to click it manually? Write code for clicking it. Selenium always runs new fresh session without cookies so it server doesn't know that you already clicked it. It may need to get cookies from browser (without using selenium) and later use it with selenium

To disable the Personalize your web experience prompt, run Edge in Guest Mode: (--guest)
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_argument("--guest")
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)

breakpoint()

driver.quit()

breakpoint() added for demonstration. (Type c and press Enter to continue from the breakpoint.)
(The experimental options remove the part with Microsoft Edge is being controlled by automated test software.)

This is a browser dialog and not part of the webpage. Because of this, Selenium cannot interact with it. You should be able to complete your script actions without even dismissing it.
